# How to make android welcome screen

Tags: android

is it possible to make first launch screen for an android app, like the screen that appears at first android OS launch.

is there anyway to make something that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Apparently there is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on this [`ShowCaseView Library`](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

With this you can make an activity like your image :

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
.setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
.setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
.setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
.hideOnTouchOutside()
.build();
```

### EDIT

Since `SwhowCaseView Library` is deprecated as his owner says :

> Currently, ShowcaseView is not under active development; issues cannot be opened and PRs will not be accepted.
>
> I've decided to make this decision because I want to rewrite the project from scratch with a far better API. A lot of things Google keep introducing in Android break ShowcaseView and it is too difficult to make these changes with the project in it's current form.
>
> The project is still available on Maven, see below for the instructions. Please see the new-scv branch for development of the new API.

Here are more `Libraries` for do what you want.

-[`MaterialShowCase Library`](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView9)

-[`TourGuide`](https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide)

-[`RoboDemo`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo)

-[`ShowCaseViewLibrary`](https://github.com/JesusM/ShowcaseViewLibrary)